# What does this notation mean? "<some range> X {0}"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there some special meaning behind multiplying a range by a set containing only zero? For example:

```
[1, 10] X {0}
```

I ran into this notation in [this paper](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/97/article_lr.pdf) and it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Once you can get away with name-dropping _yourself_ in your paper titles, you have it made!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like it's an ordinary [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), giving the set of all pairs $(a,0)$ with $1\le a\le 10$.

When the paper you link to writes (e.g., on page 222) "$q-p\in {\rm I_{disp}}\times\{0\}$", note that $p$ and $q$ are themselves pairs, so it makes sense to ask whether their difference is in such a set of pairs.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't thinking about how q - p would result in a pair that looked like (n, 0), but it makes total sense now that you point it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It means $$A \times \{0\} = \{(a,0) |a \in A \}$$

The first element must comes from $A$ and the second element is $0$.

This is called [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).